# Hyper-v virtual machine 100% cpu usage

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, hyper-v, bootcamp

I am pretty new at creating virtual machines.

I have this MacBook: Apple MacBook Pro "Core i7" 2.5 15" Mid-2015.

I run Windows 10 in a BootCamp.

I installed this virtual windows with Hyper-v inside my windows Bootcamp: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/virtual-machines

I installed a video game inside the virtual machine.

When I run the game it uses up 100% of the CPU and is so slow it's unplayable.

It doesn't matter how much virtual processors I give it.

The same game runs pretty normally with very low CPU usage on normal Bootcamp windows.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

I've figured it out.

The problem was that the virtual machine wasn't using the GPU.

I've fixed it by [following steps here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/738f05a3-a8d2-49ca-a82a-d356b83e1cd4/hyperv-quotremotefx-3d-video-adapterquot-gone-in-windows-10-1809?forum=virtualmachingmgrhyperv):

When installing everything normally and not doing any additional setup or tweaking etc. the virtual machine is not using the GPU.

I followed the answer by Victor Miasnikov in the link above.

1. Start Powershell as administrator and enter: `Get-VMRemoteFXPhysicalVideoAdapter`
2. In the returned results check if "CompatibleForVirtualization" and "Enabled" are "True". Mine luckily was.
3. Enable Host GPU for RemoteFX vGPU. Here I followed the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/hyper-v/enable-vmremotefxphysicalvideoadapter?view=win10-ps) and in my case entered this command: `Get-VMRemoteFXPhysicalVideoAdapter -Name \*Radeon\* | Enable-VMRemoteFXPhysicalVideoAdapter`
4. Add RemoteFX vGPU to your VM by entering this command: `Add-VMRemoteFx3dVideoAdapter -VMName <vmname>`
5. Open VM Settings dialog box, you can configure RemoteFX vGPU. But I think no additional configuration was necessary.
6. Start VM.